# Split one model into two models for a classification problem

Tags: machine-learning, classification, model-selection, natural-language

In the classification problem, I am working on right now, I have to classify transactions mainly with text data. The classes of the training set can easily be divided into class sets with a negative and a positive amount of the transaction. This can easily be done before training a classifier. The classes are completely independent of each other and do not share anything.

Now I was wondering if it is sensible for me to build two independent models instead of one overall model when I can split the dataset beforehand. This would lead to **two distinct classifiers**. Is there any benefit in using just one classifier except maybe a computational advantage that I do not need to train two independent classifiers? (And always have to split incoming data before) I think that the separate classifiers can yield better results but I'm not sure if this is something a more experienced ML engineer would do.

Comment: Do you want two classifiers for the two classes ( Positive and Negative )? If yes, that won't help, as a classifier needs at least two classes to distinguish samples.

Comment: No, it is a multi-class problem ~20 classes for each positive and negative transactions